# how can I save GridView rows and call them same after Postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am learning asp.net and I have a dynamic `GridView`,
meaning the `GridView` rows change after a search,
meaning its `SelectCommand` changes.

### My aim:

1 - To save the `GridView` and its rows resulting of a search,

2 - and get the same `GridView` (results of a search) after any number of pages postbacks.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your code in page_load inside Page.IsPostback Property like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
             // Initially bind your grid view like
                GridView1.DataSource = "DataSource";
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

**After Search**

> In searching scenarion you have to pass the user input as a parameter and search
>   according to user input and call you DataBind method again to refresh
>   your grid view related to user input.

**Temporary Storage**

Firstly you need to create a temporary table in the database, Your database structure will be look like the fields you want to show on grid or related to search query selected value.

**Example**

if you are selecting Name,Address,Phonenumber,Salary etc fields from search query then you have to create those all fields into your temporary database table.

**Now you have Question.**

1) Where to store data into Temprary table.

When you are getting value from database filter by search then run a insert query and put those data into your temporary table as well for furthur use.

2) Table must be persistent from page to page.

You are saving data into your database as a temporary table so it must be persistent.

Now you have the searched data into your temporary table so whenever you want to show searched data, bind your grid view with temporary table means use temporary table name into your query like

> Select * from temporarytablename

Hope you understand.

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, what you mean please by `pass the user input as a parameter`, do you mean by using QueryString? If that's so then how to keep those QueryString values after that I go from a page to another to the GridView page in the end? How can I keep those inputs?

Comment: i am not talking about query string,it means that pass your user input text to your method in which you are using your "select query",let us suppose that you have a list of months from jan to dec into your database, now user want data for April month then they will enter April in search box and hit enter or any event, now you pass that "April" to your query to search for only April like,"Select * from tablename where month = "April"",after getting data bind your gridview again.Now your grid view will show Data for April and that's the thing user want and functionality of searching.

Comment: Thanks again Rahul, and thanks for the explanation it is very useful, but I'm sorry: the problem is not with the search, the problem is if there is a way to keep the search (perhaps the Select query results?) that is to keep the GridView resulting of a search, in order to call it back later. Example: I do the search that you mentioned in your comment, then I go to another page and return to page of GridView again, I will see that the search results are not saved. That is the problem: how can I keep the GridView after doing a search, and leaving page? The problem is not with the search.

Comment: ok ok for that i have a solution as well, you need to use a temporary table in which you need to save your searched data and when ever you want to show it bind your Data tool with that temporary table..

Comment: and how can i go about doing that if you don't mind? An example or a link would be very kind.

Comment: dear i have no code related to that and don't know about any link.but i will explain you that how you  achieve this protocol.

Comment: So I will look now about how and where I can store the GridView to a temporary table + if we can call this table after postbacks to bind GridView to it. That's if the temporary `table is persistent` from a page to another, do you know? Because that's what is needed.

Comment: i m edited my answer for your result please give me some time.

Comment: Cool. take your time if I know something about it too I will tell you, is there a PM in stackoverflow?

Comment: yes there is a Chat option as well for PM (personal messages) in stackoverflow? ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29177/discussion-between-rahul-and-compliance)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check the [`Page.IsPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) property before you bind data to your GridView. Try something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
      GridView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
      GridView1.DataBind();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick, that's for the search but the problem is not that, the problem is not the search, the problem is how to keep the GridView as is after having made a search and get it back later after leaving the page where the gridview exists and coming back.

Answer (score 0):

The ability of an ASP.Net control like a `GridView` to retain state after Postbacks to the same page is inherent if you enable [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the page and control, provided that the user doesn't leave the `.aspx` page.

As others have mentioned, one of the common reasons why `ViewState` doesn't work correctly is if you inadvertently rebind new / different data to the `GridView` after a postback - you can avoid doing this by checking for `!IsPostBack` (i.e. bind the initial data to the GridView only on the first GET access to the page, or rebind it explicitly e.g. if the user changes his / her search filter etc).

If you need to retain the original search results after the user navigates **away** from the page containing the GridView, you will need to cache the state elsewhere, such as in [SessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx), although storing large amounts of data in SessionState isn't recommended. In this case, you might instead save the filter or query that the user ran to obtain the data in `SessionState`, rather than the actual data returned from the search.

Comment: Thanks StuartLC, it's ok I'm learning the approach if that's possible in asp.net, to save the gridview as is after a search then leave to a page then go back to same gridview rows, so you're right that's what I need to do but...

Comment: ...what do you mean by `save the filter or query that the user ran`, do you mean to save the SelectCommand? or something else? In either way how can I go about doing that to `obtain the data in SessionState`? I do not understand this neither I'm afraid.